# no puedo comparar

Tags: java, comparaciones

Estoy creando un código para "comparar" el nombre de unos medicamentos, pero no se bien los métodos dentro de los if  (en este caso son los métodos `GetText` y `SetText`), y no puedo arreglarlo.

Según vi, para variables tipo `String` debo usar el método `.equals()`, lo cual ya hice, al igual que los dos iguales para comparar (==), pero aún así no logro hacerlo funcionar

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class VentanaMedicamentos extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private Jlabel label1, label2, label3, label4;
    private JLabel labelNoHay;
    private JTextArea area1, area2, area3;
    private JButton boton1, boton2;
    Int medic;
    String med1, med2, med3;
    String descr1, descr2, descr3;
    JScrollPane scroll1, scroll2, scroll3;

    public VentanaMedicamentos(){
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("Medicamentos");
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0,0,255));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        VentanaUno mensajero = new VentanaUno();
        num_med = mensajero.medic;
        VentanaUno mensaje = new VentanaUno();
        med_1 = mensaje.med1;
        VentanaUno iris = new VentanaUno();
        med_2 = iris.med2;
        VentanaUno hermes = new VentanaUno();
        med_3 = hermes.med3;

        label1 = new JLabel ("hemos detectado " + num_med + " medicamentos" );
        label1.setBounds(50,50,300,50);
        label1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", 3, 16));
        label1.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        add(label1);

        label2 = new JLabel (med_1);
        label2.setBounds(110,50,300,50);
        label2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", 3, 16));
        label2.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        add(label2);

        label3 = new JLabel (med_2);
        label3.setBounds(300,50,300,50);
        label3.setFont(new Font("Calibri", 3, 16));
        label3.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        add(label3);

        label4 = new JLabel (med_4);
        label4.setBounds(500,100,300,50);
        label4.setFont(new Font("Calibri", 3, 16));
        label4.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        add(label4);

        area1 = new JTextArea (descr1);
        area1.setBounds(110,150,300,50);
        area1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", 3, 16));
        area1.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        area1.setEditable(false);
        scroll1 = new JScrollPane(area1);
        add(scroll1);

        area2 = new JTextArea (descr2);
        area2.setBounds(300,150,300,50);
        area2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", 3, 16));
        area2.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        area2.setEditable(false);
        scroll2 = new JScrollPane(area2);
        add(scroll2);

        area3 = new JTextArea (descr3);
        area3.setBounds(500,150,300,50);
        area3.setFont(new Font("Calibri", 3, 16));
        area3.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        area3.setEditable(false);
        scroll3 = new JScrollPane(area3);
        add(scroll3);

        boton1 = new JButton("volver");
        boton1.setBounds(100,700,300,50);
        boton1.setBackground(new Color(255,0,0));
        boton1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", 3, 16));
        boton1.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
        boton1.setEnabled(true);
        boton1.addActionListener(this);
        add(boton1);

        boton2 = new JButton("continuar");
        boton2.setBounds(700,700,300,50);
        boton2.setBackground(new Color(255,0,0));
        boton2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", 3, 16));
        boton2.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
        boton2.setEnabled(true);
        boton2.addActionListener(this);
        add(boton2);

        labelNoHay = new JLabel ();
        labelNoHay.setBounds(700,1200,300,50);
        labelNoHay.setFont(new Font("Calibri", 3, 16));
        labelNoHay.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        add(labelNoHay);

        if (label1.getText().equals(levotiroxina)){

            area1.setText();

        }if (label1.getText().equals(metformina)){

            area1.setText();

        }if (label1.getText().equals(enalapril)){

            area1.setText();

        }if (label1.getText().equals(aspirina)){

            area1.setText();

        }if (label1.getText().equals(amlodipino)){

            area1.setText();

        }if (label2.getText().equals(levotiroxina)){

            area2.setText();

        }if (label2.getText().equals(metformina)){

            area2.setText();

        }if (label2.getText().equals(enalapril)){

            area2.setText();

        }if (label2.getText().equals(aspirina)){

            area2.setText();

        }if (label2.getText().equals(amlodipino)){

            area2.setText();

        }if (label3.getText().equals(levotiroxina)){

            area3.setText();

        }if (label3.getText().equals(metformina)){

            area3.setText();

        }if (label3.getText().equals(enalapril)){

            area3.setText();

        }if (label3.getText().equals(aspirina)){

            area3.setText();

        }if (label3.getText().equals(aspirina)){

            area3.setText();

        }else{

            labelNoHay.setText("lo sentimos, hay un medicamento que aun no está en nuestro sistema");

        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            if (e.getSource() == boton1){

                VentanaUno ventana1 = new VentanaUno();
                ventana1.setBounds(0,0,2000,2000);
                ventana1.setVisible(true);
                ventana1.setResizable(false);
                ventana1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            }if (e.getSource() == boton2) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No se entiende que estas tratando de hacer...

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. ¿Qué tipo de dato son `enalapril`, `aspirina`, etc? ¿Qué error te da al compilar?

Answer (score 1):

con el método equals de java debería bastar para comparar 2 String, por lo que te recomiendo validar los valores que se están ingresando por pantalla, como buena practica de programacion te recomiendo usar la contantes antes de la variables al comparar ejemplo.

```
if (aspirina.equals(label2.getText())){
  area2.setText();
}
```

por otra parte, tambien existe el metodo equalsIgnoreCase

El método equalsIgnoreCase () compara dos cadenas independientemente del caso (lower or upper) de la cadena. Este método devuelve verdadero si el argumento no es nulo y representa un caso de ignorar String equivalente, de lo contrario es falso.

saludos.

Comment: Gracias, pero me quedo una duda, osea uso el método . equalsIgnoreCase, uso lower o upper?

Comment: quiere decir que equalsIgnoreCase, compara 2 String aunque tengan mayúsculas o minúsculas.

Ejemplo   Hola  = HoLa  con equalsIgnoreCase es True.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que hubiera sido más fácil con switch:

```
String medicamento=label1.getText();

if(medicamento.equals(""))
{ 
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"lo sentimos, hay un medicamento que aun no está en nuestro sistema");
} else {    
switch(medicamento)
          {
           case "levotiroxina": area1.setText(); break;
             .
             .
             .
           case N : area1.setText(); break;
          }
      }
```